# How to use list of RegEx's when defining LxmlLinkExtractor rule

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to know how I can define a list of RegEx's outside of my Scrapy spider, and then read the RegEx's into a **LxmlLinkExtractor**.

I'm using the current code:

```
file = open("myFile.txt")
regexs = [rule.strip() for rule in file.readlines()]
file.close()
return regexs
```

The returned value is then passed as a parameter as follows:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(regexs, )), callback='parse_file')
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* work:

```
regexs = [rule.strip() for rule in file.readlines()]
LinkExtractor(allow=regexs, callback='parse_file')
```

See more here about the allow parameter:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml

Comment: Great. Accepting the answer is the way to go if it worked for you, so it doesn't remain cataloged as "unanswered" :)